# iOS7: Pop-up picker on touch of a button (with blurred background)

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, uipickerview, picker

What I'm trying to figure out is how to pop-up a PickerView from the bottom of the screen when I press a button. And a blurred background would be nice ;D
I saw some setting the inputView of a textfield but as I got no textfield I can't do that.

Here's a screenshot from the iTunes Store where they do it exactly how I want it to be:
http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/1bs30sz2ovmk0oa/screen.png

Comment: are you using storyboard?

Comment: Yes I am using storyboard

Answer (score 0):

Create a UIViewController with UIPickerView in the storyboard and set an identifier. 
Connect the button to it and choose view/push (depends if you want to cover the entire screen or not). once it's called you can change the setting of how it will appear.
You can get the UIViewController from the storyboard like this:

```
     UIViewController  *viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:vcName];
```

You can also save a property in your UIViewController of a UIView which contains a UIPickerView. 
Once the button is pressed call a method which fade/slide the view with animation inside.

```
   [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
   [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.30];
        self.pikerView.frame = CGRectMake(100,100,SCREEN_WIDTH,300); //something like that
   [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: But how can I not let it cover the whole screen?

Comment: You can determine different UIViewControllerSize in the size inspector (4th tab on the left sidebar) change it to freedom and then you can adjust it

Comment: I tried that, but the view with the picker moves then to the center of the screen which is not what I wanted

Comment: Doesn't it help if you'll change the CGRectMake to CGRectMake(0,SCREEN_WIDTH - pickerView.height,SCREEN_WIDTH,pickerView.height)?